# Switchable enhancements one by one. Possible?

Tags: abap

Working on the current project I'm going to make highly configurable app by multiple parameters: country, region-specific and business-case wise configurability.
Considering the ways to implement this I evaluated Switch Framework, which is the foundational part of SAP industry solutions delivery, and it is also used in Enhancement framework.

Despite heavily used in standard solutions, I rarely saw the real use cases of Switch Framework with custom developments and with custom enhancements. Most of the blogs about it are dated to 2002-2009 years and I found little info about using Switch Framework now.

https://blogs.sap.com/2009/01/15/how-to-get-the-most-from-the-enhancement-and-switch-framework-as-a-customer-or-partner-tips-from-the-experts
https://blogs.sap.com/2008/01/07/the-three-use-cases-of-the-enhancement-and-switch-framework-part-2
https://blogs.sap.com/2008/01/14/the-three-use-cases-of-the-enhancement-and-switch-framework-part-3

Neither official [Switch Framework docu](https://help.sap.com/viewer/1d51ac4c098042528cadb1d5bcb1ab23/7.40.20/en-US/afe8b540afc87c2ae10000000a155106.html) helps, nor [Enhancement Framework docu](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/94/9cdc40132a8531e10000000a1550b0/content.htm).

By my hands-on tests I found out that using the switch framework I can switch on and off enhancement **only** if they lays in different packages, by assigning the package to the switch and assigning the switch to the correspondent business function.

[image]

This finding of mine is confirmed by this diagram from the above blogs

[image]

I need more fine-grained switching for enhancements, being able to enable or disable them independently, without putting each enhancement into separate package.

**The question:** is it possible apply switch to a single enhancement, not to a package?

If not possible via Switch Framework, is there any other technique I can use?

Comment: Better use BAdIs along with filters. Switch framework is for switching complete features. Moreover it can be dangerous if you have database tables in the switch, switching off will drop the data.

Comment: BADis are much more hassle to maintain comparing to code enhancements. Regarding tables it is not true. During my tests I successfully switched business function on and off and the data in DB table left intact. Maybe am doing smth wrong, though, I do it just assigning the table to the business function package, no other actions done.

Comment: You're right. Just tested now (in 7.52), it only concerns the columns from the append structures (and I guess it concerns also the includes).